# copy_to_user doesn't copy all bytes

Tags: c

I am trying to copy a value from the kernel to userspace but I am haivng torubles with the fact that copy_to_user doesn't copy all bytes of the string.

```
size = strlen(node-> from)* sizeof(char)
copy_to_user ( (char* ) from, %node->from, size)
```

Comment: Two thoughts: 1) If you copy strlen * sizeof(char), you will be one byte short, because strlen does not include the null terminator. 2) The [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-api/API---copy-to-user.html) says this returns the number of bytes which are not copied. Is the return value non-zero?

Comment: `* sizeof(char)` is really not necessary, a `char` always has size 1.

Comment: It's not a bad idea to avoid 'strings', (NUL-terminated char arrays), in kernel code, if possible.  Store the size so you can handle embedded nulls.